# How to search for all computers running memcached on shodan

Tags: vulnerability, software, shodan

Memcached is a caching software typically used in web servers. Many web servers like wikipedia, wordpress, flickr cache their data using Memcached software. Memcached server typically runs on port 11211. A client software (such as web server) can make get and set queries to memcached server. As clients can store sensitive information in Memcached, it is not advisable to connect Memcached servers to internet.

For my research, I would like to search the active memcached servers that are connected to internet. A simple search query on shodan.io would be "port:11211". As I only want "active" memcached servers, I want to list the servers which store more than 1000 items (cur_items > 1000). May I know how to query shodan?

Answer (score 3):

Shodan sends the STATS command and that information can be seen in the Memcached banner and metadata:

https://www.shodan.io/search?query=product%3Amemcached

You can use that information to see the number of stored items though we don't allow filtering by that information via the API/ website so you need to download the search results to process it locally.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/132165)

Comment: I've modified the answer to be self-contained.

Comment: Cool to have someone connected to Shodan drop by and leave a good answer. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

To get information about the number items you could use the `STATS` command after connecting to a memcached instance.  Shodan doesn't run commands against all the servers it scans, rather it makes simple connections and records the response.

You can't connect to random machines and start running commands, that's not legal.  I mention this because the way you worded your question it sounds like you're attempting to enumerate memcached servers to use in reflected DDOS attacks.

Comment: I mailed to shodan support and they mentioned that such a query is not possible. I don't want to conduct any attack though. I want to mention the stats in my class project report.

Comment: Yeah, there's no legal way to collect this information without permission from every system owner you connect to and query.